# Is it possible to not reorder elements when using d3.join?

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, data-visualization, visualization

In `d3`, we may change the order of elements in a selection, for example by using `raise`.

Yet, when we rebind the data and use `join`, this order is discarded.

This does not happen when we use "the old way" of binding data, using `enter` and `merge`.

See following fiddle where you can click a circle (for example the blue one) to bring it to front. When you click "*redraw*", the circles go back to their original z-ordering when using `join`, but not when using `enter` and `merge`.

Can I achive that the circles keep their z-ordering and still use `join`?

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  v: 10,
  c: 'red'
}, {
  id: 2,
  v: 30,
  c: 'blue'
}, {
  id: 3,
  v: 60,
  c: 'green'
}]

let nDrawCall = 0

function redraw() {
  nDrawCall++
  //svg1 with old enter-merge pattern that works
  const circles = d3.select('#svg1')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(data, d => d.id)
  circles
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .on('click', function() {
      d3.select(this).raise()
    })
    .merge(circles)
    .attr('cx', d => d.v * nDrawCall)
    .attr('cy', d => d.v)
    .attr('r', d => d.v)
    .attr('fill', d => d.c)
    
  //svg2 with new join pattern that sadly reorders
  d3.select('#svg2')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(data, d => d.id)
    .join(enter => enter
      .append('circle')
      .on('click', function() {
        d3.select(this).raise()
      })
    )
    .attr('cx', d => d.v * nDrawCall)
    .attr('cy', d => d.v)
    .attr('r', d => d.v)
    .attr('fill', d => d.c)
}

function reset() {
  nDrawCall = 0
  redraw()
}

redraw()

/*
while (true) {
  iter++
  console.log(iter)
  sleepFor(500)
}
*/
```

```css
svg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="redraw()">
      Redraw
    </button>
    <button onclick="reset()">
      Reset
    </button>
    <div>
      <svg id="svg1" />  
      <svg id="svg2" />
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`join` does an implicit `order` after merging the enter- and update-selection, see https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/91245ee124ec4dd491e498ecbdc9679d75332b49/src/selection/join.js#L14.

The selection order after the data binding in your example is still red, blue, green even if the document order is changed. So the circles are reordered to the original order using `join`.

You can get around that by changing the data binding reflecting the change in the document order. I did that here, by moving the datum of the clicked circle to the end of the data array.

```js
let data = [{
  id: 1,
  v: 10,
  c: 'red'
}, {
  id: 2,
  v: 30,
  c: 'blue'
}, {
  id: 3,
  v: 60,
  c: 'green'
}]

let nDrawCall = 0

function redraw() {
  nDrawCall++
  d3.select('#svg2')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(data, d => d.id)
    .join(enter => enter
      .append('circle')
      .on('click', function() {
        const circle = d3.select(this).raise();
        data.push(data.splice(data.indexOf(circle.datum()), 1)[0]);
      })
    )
    .attr('cx', d => d.v * nDrawCall)
    .attr('cy', d => d.v)
    .attr('r', d => d.v)
    .attr('fill', d => d.c)
}

function reset() {
  nDrawCall = 0
  redraw()
}

redraw()
```

```css
svg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="redraw()">
      Redraw
    </button>
    <button onclick="reset()">
      Reset
    </button>
    <div>
      <svg id="svg2" />
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the highlighting of the respective source code line. I really do not want to change the data array order but only the document order. My app implements the command pattern, and the `do` and `undo` operations get unnecessarily complex if I change the data array order. [I wrote an issue on d3's GitHub page to ask whether a `join` without implicit `order` call might be introduced.](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/issues/299)